# Evaluate ImportJSON() custom function less often

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am using this importJSON script: https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

Screenshot of my sheet: https://puu.sh/IWNt6/5d8a15138d.png

I make multiple calls in cells and I am reaching max quotas limit very often. Therefore I would like to add a timer to update all cells every 1 hour, instead of automatic updates.
Any ideas how can I do it? I've tried to add trigger (createTimeDrivenTriggers) but it doesn't work since it's custom function (cell function).

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [ImportJSON()](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) as a custom function in your spreadsheet formulas, Google Sheets will refresh those formulas from time to time, most often when opening the spreadsheet. This will cause repeated fetching of the same data even if it has not changed.

If you do not need to update the results quite that often, you can also write your own script function that uses ImportJSON() to get the data and then stores the values in the spreadsheet. You can then run your function only when required, perhaps through a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) or a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), or a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

The function could look something like this:

```
function refreshJSON() {
  const parameters = [
    {
      url: 'https://url1...',
      cell: 'Sheet1!A1',
    },
    {
      url: 'https://url2...',
      cell: 'Sheet1!N1',
    },
    {
      url: 'https://url3...',
      cell: 'Sheet2!A1',
    },
  ];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  parameters.forEach(spec => {
    const data = ImportJSON(spec.url);
    ss.getRange(spec.cell)
      .offset(0, 0, data.length, data[0].length)
      .setValues(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This seem like a decent solution to my problem, however I am using CONCATENATE function to build every link based on a cell. Is there any way to use it in your script?
For example:
```=importjson(CONCATENATE("https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?page_size=9&status=active&sell_metadata=%7B%22image%22:[%22https://card.godsunchained.com/%3Fid=",Cards!A2,"%26q=4%22]%7D&buy_token_type=ETH&order_by=buy_quantity&direction=asc"),)```

Where ```Cards!A2``` is an ID: https://puu.sh/IWRzN/fdd244ee71.png

Comment: Also I just tested the script and it's kinda slow with many urls. Is there any way to improve its performance?

Comment: You can concatenate values in the script using the JavaScript `+` operator. The new requirements you mention were not specified in your question. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).